# Cant start IReport 3.0 after uninstalling Java 8

Tags: ireport

I have 3 jdks installed in my machine, 1.6, 1.7, and 1.8. IReport 3.0 was working fine before removing jdk 8. But after removing jdk 8, IReport 3.0 wont start.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Error:

'javaw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What error message are you getting when you try to start it?

Comment: No errors were thrown! Is there an error log for this? Where can I find it?

Comment: Try launching it from the command line.  That should show you your error.  It's probably that your JAVA_HOME environment variable got unset when you uninstalled jdk8.  Or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uninstalled jdk8, it removed `[java location]/bin` from your `Path` environment variable.  You need to add the bin path of whichever jdk installation you want to use to `Path`.